# Calculating the Payout of an Unusual Digital Slot Machine

Tags: probability, statistics

Say you have a digital slot machine. Rather than using virtual reels, this slot machine generates results using predetermined probabilities for a given symbol appearing in any position.

Given:

- Five 'reels' (positions for a symbol to appear)
- Wild symbols exist (and have their own probability of appearing)
- Matches must be left-aligned

**How does one calculate the probability of each possible number of matches, 0-5, for a given symbol?**

(A 'match' of 1 would mean a symbol appears in the left-most position, but is not followed by itself or a Wild.)

Please include in your response a formula which is readable by a layman (I'm no mathemetician).

---

What follows is a description of my attempts to solve this problem.

As an example: the Cherries symbol pays 4x the bet for 3 matches. In any given position, Cherries has a 20% chance of appearing, and Wild has a 2% chance of appearing.

My first attempt at calculating this probability was $0.2 * (0.2 + 0.02)^2 = 0.00968$. At least one Cherries, plus two more symbols which are either Cherries or Wild. $4 * 0.00968 = 3.872%$ pay for 3 Cherries.

It then occurred to me that this probability would seem to also include the probability of getting a match of 4 Cherries and would need to exclude the chance of the next symbol being Cherries or Wild. Thus, I updated the calculation to be $0.2 * (0.2 + 0.02)^2 - (0.2 * (0.2 + 0.02)^3) = .0075504$, giving a payout of ~3.020%. (This step is skipped if we are testing for 5 matches, since 6 matches is impossible.) Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "matches must be left-aligned"? Also, this may just be my ignorance of slot machines, but what is a match and how does the system work?

Comment: Matches must be left-aligned: This means the first symbol must either be the match symbol or a wild symbol. For instance, if in our five reels we had Cherries; Grapes; Cherries; Cherries; Cherries, this would only be a match of 1 because Grapes is not a match. If our five reels were Wild; Cherries; Grapes; Cherries; Cherries, this would be a match of 2.

Comment: A match is a group of matching symbols, and Wilds are also included as part of a match. Generally speaking, the higher number of matches you have, the more the slot machine will pay (but some symbols are worth more than others, so 2 Bar symbols may be worth more than 3 Cherries, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

There are two different quantities we can calculate: the *probability* of a match with some number of symbols, and the *expected payout* of a match with some number of symbols.

Let us do probability first. Say you have the Cherries symbol, which appears with a probability $p_c$, and the Wild symbol, which appears with a probability $p_w$. In your case, this would be $p_c = 0.2$ and $p_w = 0.02$. If we want to get exactly $n \geq 3$ matching symbols then the probability is
$$n \cdot p_c \cdot (p_c + p_w)^2 \cdot (p_c + p_w)^{n-3} \cdot (1 - (p_c + p_w))$$
(For $n = 5$, as you said, the last term does not need to be taken into account because there is no sixth symbol.) If we want exactly $2$ matching symbols, then the probability is
$$2 \cdot p_c \cdot (p_c + p_w) \cdot (1 - (p_c + p_w))$$
Exactly $1$ matching symbol:
$$p_c \cdot (1 - (p_c + p_w))$$
$0$:
$$1 - (p_c + p_w)$$

This is similar to what you did, except that you subtracted the probability of getting a matching symbol; you should instead multiply by the probability of *not* getting a matching symbol, which is $1 = 100\%$ minus whatever the probability is.

When doing probabilities, you should always remember that 'and' is translated as 'multiply', while 'or' is translated as 'add'. You want a Cherry before *and* no Cherries afterwards, so you multiply. Subtraction of probabilities does not have any meaning here.

The expected payoff is slightly trickier. We assume that 3 Cherries give a payoff of 4x, 4 Cherries give a payoff of 15x, and 5 Cherries, 50x. 0, 1, or 2 Cherries are worthless, in that you actually *lose* the money you bet. If you bet 1 monetary unit, then your expected payoff *from Cherries* is
$$
\begin{align}
e =\ &(1 - (p_c + p_w)) \cdot (-1) + p_c \cdot (1 - (p_c + p_w)) \cdot (-1) + \\
&2 \cdot p_c \cdot (p_c + p_w) \cdot (1 - (p_c + p_w)) \cdot (-1) + 3 \cdot p_c \cdot (p_c + p_w)^2 \cdot (1 - (p_c + p_w)) \cdot 4 + \\
&4 \cdot p_c \cdot (p_c + p_w)^3 \cdot (1 - (p_c + p_w)) \cdot 15 + 5 \cdot p_c \cdot (p_c + p_w)^4 \cdot 50
\end{align}
$$
Here, we are adding the products of probabilities and the corresponding payoffs, where for the first two terms, the payoff is $-1$ because you lose money. Note that this is the expected payoff from Cherries only; we are not including the possibility that you get 0 Cherries but instead get 4 Apples, which gives you a lot of money. To do that, we have to calculate the payoffs from each type of symbol separately and add them together.

Using the example probabilities you have given, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
e =\ &(1 - 0.22) \cdot (-1) + 0.2 \cdot (1 - 0.22) \cdot (-1) + \\
&2 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.22 \cdot (1 - 0.22) \cdot (-1) + 3 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.22^2 \cdot (1 - 0.22) \cdot 4 + \\
&4 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.22^3 \cdot (1 - 0.22) \cdot 15 + 5 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.22^4 \cdot 50 \\
\approx\ &-0.697
\end{align}
$$

So an average, you will lose $0.697$ monetary units, which is an average payout of $30.3\%$ when you play this game *for Cherries* (we are *not* counting other symbols). The expected payoffs for other symbols are also likely to be negative; in short, don't gamble! :)

Feel free to ask for clarification in the comments.

*Edit*: From your comments, I gather that the probabilities of $0.2$ and $0.02$ are just one part of the total probabilities of these symbols appearing. You can plug the actual figures into the formula above and get the correct average payout.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough response! I'm finding, however, that your formula for calculating match probabilities and mine give the exact same result (note that I am not subtracting the probability of getting some other symbol, but the probability of getting 4 matches). Actually, I was using your calculation at one point in trying to solve this problem, but it confused me in that it didn't seem to take into account the fact that the non-Cherries, non-Wild symbol *must* come last. By multiplying each of the probabilities together, aren't we saying that the order does not matter?

Comment: I am looking for a flaw in the logic because I find when I simulate spins, the actual result does not match what is predicted by these formulas. For instance, your formula and mine predict the odds of 1-5 matches for Cherries as 14.55%; 3.00%; 0.62%; 0.13%; 0.03%, respectively. In practice, I see matches as ~14.25%; ~3.23%; ~0.68%; ~0.14%; ~0.038% across one million simulated spins.

Comment: Also, in the world of slots, I've found that pays are generally given as what they pay back as a percentage of the amount paid to play rather than what they cost. In your example, would the Cherries pay percentage be found as 1 - 0.917 = 8.3%?

Comment: (Also note, the predicted odds and simulated results above take into account a more complicated reality of symbol odds. Symbols don't have just one probability of appearing, but multiple probabilities of appearing, each with its own probability of being the selected probability. Given the fixed probability provided in my example, the predicted probabilities of getting 1-5 matches would be 15.60%; 3.43%; 0.76%; 0.17%; and 0.05%, respectively.)

Comment: Re. comment 1: if the order did not matter, then we would have to include a multiplier like $n!$ to account for all orders that the symbols can appear in. Here, though we're not specifying the order explicitly, there is only one possible order we are calculating, which is the left-to-right order.

Re. comment 2: probabilities won't match *exactly*, because 1. they're *probabilities* and 2. you're probably using a pseudorandom number generator somewhere, which is biased.

Re. comment 3: Yes.

Re. comment 4: could you elaborate on this? This might affect the probabilities in your simulation.

Comment: First, thanks again! I really appreciate your help with this. Re: 1: I guess what's confusing me is the fact that we're multiplying probabilities. Since, e.g. 0.25 * 0.5 gives the same result as 0.5 * 0.25, it feels like the importance of the order is being ignored.

Comment: Re: 2: I understand that the probabilities won't match exactly, but across a million spins I get very consistent results. This consistency leads me to think there's something wrong with my prediction. I have considered the possibility that the pseudorandom generator may be at fault. That may prove to be the true culprit. I'm running simulations in Chrome, which uses the improved xor generator, but it's still imperfect.

Comment: Re: 3: I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write a general function for the formula you provided. The function I'm using now (getPays) simply takes the calculated probability for each symbol and match count and multiplies that probability times its respective pay multiplier. I then have a separate function which takes the output from getPays and aggregates the percentages together. So for Cherries I get match probabilities from 3-5 as ~0.62%; ~0.13%; ~0.03% times pays for 3-5 as 4x; 15x; 50x giving payout from 3-5 as 2.49%; 1.95%; 1.73%. Adding each together gives 6.17%. Is this flawed?

Comment: Re: 4: We have 6 sets of 'rates' (chance of a symbol appearing in a given position). Each rate set has a probability of being selected to determine whether a symbol appears. (Actually, each rate set has four probabilities depending on which 'mode' we're using, but we're assuming we're using only mode 1, so we can ignore that additional complexity.) The probabilities of each rate set add up to 1. For Cherries, the rates are 20% @ a probability of 43.35%, 18% @ 20%, 18% @ 25%, 0.1 @ 5.3%, 6% @ 0.55%, and 18% @ 5.6%. Thus, the overall probability of a Cherries appearing is actually ~18.34%.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that there was an error in the rate set probabilities -- they didn't quite add up to one. I've adjusted at final set to have a probability of 5.8%. Predicted odds for matches 1-5 are now 14.58%; 3.01%; 0.62%; 0.13%; 0.03% (which still does not match the simulated result). I've also tested setting the first rate set to a probability of 1 and each of the remaining 5 to 0 and have found that expected and actual results still do not match (which seems to indicate that the error does not lie in the aggregation of rate set probabilities, or at least does not only lie there).

Comment: Correction: pseudorandom number generation is done with the xorshift128+ algorithm. See: http://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/12/theres-mathrandom-and-then-theres.html

Comment: It would perhaps be simpler to 'condense' the probabilities of probabilities into a single probability, like you just did. Using those probabilities would probably yield more accurate results. And as long as the total probability of all symbols appearing adds up to 1, the model is valid. I don't really know about the 6.17% figure; if the formula and the probabilities are correct, then the figure is.

Comment: The reason I'm not condensing the probabilities is because my output includes tables for match probabilities and pays for each rate set to assist in adjusting each.
The reason I ask about my means of calculating pays is because when I try to calculate the Cherries pay using your formula I get a different result: $(1−0.20442)*(−1)+0.18341*(1−0.20442)*(−1)+0.18341*0.20442*(1−0.20442)*(−1)+0.18341*(0.20442)^2*(1−0.20442)*4+0.18341*(0.20442)^3*(1−0.20442)*15+0.18341*(0.20442)^4*50 = -0.91222529189$ or a payout of ~8.777%

Comment: You're getting a different payout because the numbers I used in my answer are different (I used 4, 8, 20 while you are using 4, 15, 50)

Comment: It seems even using the same pay multipliers, the two methods give different answers. Let's use 20% chance of Cherries, 2% chance of Wild, and multipliers of 4x, 15x, and 20x.

Multiplying each match odd by its multiplier and summing them together:
$(0.2 * 0.22^2 * (1-0.22) * 4) + (0.2 * 0.22^3 * (1-0.22) * 15) + (0.2 * 0.22^4 * 50) = 0.07854352$ or ~7.854%

Calculating payout directly:
$1 + ((1 - 0.22) * (-1) + 0.2 * (1 - 0.22) * (-1) + 0.2 * 0.22 * (1 - 0.22) * (-1) + 0.2 * (0.22)^2 * (1 - 0.22) * 4 + 0.2 * (0.22)^3 * (1 - 0.22) * 15 + 0.2 * (0.22) ^ 4 * 50) = 0.10822352$ or ~10.822%

Comment: There may be another problem: You have said that we are calculating the probability in such a way that guarantees a specific order. In this case, the order for e.g. 3 Cherries is:

1st: Cherries symbol
2nd: Cherries symbol or Wild symbol
3rd: Cherries symbol or Wild symbol
4th: A symbol which is neither Cherries or Wild

If that is true, the formula is not accurately predicting the payout of the slot machine, because in reality the first symbol can also be a Wild. The important thing is that at least one of the first three symbols is a Cherries symbol, but not necessarily the first symbol.

Comment: Oh, that changes things... The method to calculate the probabilities is the same, only you need to multiply by 3 in places to account for the three possible positions of the Cherries symbol.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Would you mind updating your answer to include this change? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Since the formula is written as though we're betting all our money toward just the Cherries symbol, if as suggested I use the formula to calculate each symbol's pay and sum them all together, it seems the result will be that we lose much more than 100% of our bet (which is of course impossible). How should this be accounted for? Rather than using the -1 figure, should a figure of $-1/c$ be used, where *c* is the total count of symbols? In this way, we would be dividing our bet evenly across all the symbols we're betting on matching.

Comment: Yes, that would divide the bet equally. A smarter player might choose to assign different bets for different symbols, maybe, but the method remains the same.

Comment: I'm afraid slot machines don't allow players to bet on specific symbols, however smart they might be. :P

Using the updated formula for calculating match odds, my odds for 1 match look exactly right, but 2+ match odds are way off of what we would expect based on simulation results, where before they were very close...

Can you explain where the n-3 is coming from?

For comparison's sake, our approximate expected result for Cherries at 20%, 2%:

15.6%, 3.7%, 0.84%, 0.18%, 0.05%

And using the formula provided in your answer:

15.6%, 6.86%, 2.27%, 0.66%, 0.23%

Comment: And using the formula we had previously:

15.6%, 3.43%, 0.76%, 0.17%, 0.05% (Note the odds for 1 match were also exactly right here, as were the odds for 5 matches)

Answer (score 0):

For $m$ matches we consider symbol sequences with C=cherry, W=wild, X=neither cherry nor wild with probabilities $p_c=0.2, p_w=0.02, p_x=1-p_c-p_w=0.78$.

Probability of $m=0$ is $p_w^5+p_w^4p_x+p_w^3p_x+p_w^2p_x+p_wp_x+p_x=0.795918$
which are sequences all-5 W (I'm not considering this a match)
or of 4 to 0 W's followed by X.

Probability of $m=1$ is one X at 2nd and one C at first: $p_cp_x=0.156$.
Note that W at first and X at second is not considered a match.

Probability of $m=2$ is one X at 3rd, 1 to 2 C's and the other W's in any order
at 1st and 2nd:
$\sum_{i=1}^2 \binom{2}{i} p_c^i p_w^{2-i}p_x =  0.03744$.

Probability of $m=3$ is one X at 4th, 1 to 3 C's and the other W's in any order
at 1st to 3rd:
$\sum_{i=1}^3 \binom{3}{i} p_c^i p_w^{3-i}p_x =  0.0082992$.

Probability of $m=4$ is one X at 5th, 1 to 4 C's and the other W's in any order
at 1st to 4th:
$\sum_{i=1}^4 \binom{4}{i} p_c^i p_w^{4-i}p_x =  0.001827072$.

Probability of $m=5$ is no X, 1 to 5 C's and the other W's in any order:
$\sum_{i=1}^5 \binom{5}{i} p_c^i p_w^{5-i} =  0.00051536$.